# Android signed apk build error : The <service> element must be a direct child of the <application> element

Tags: android, android-manifest, signed-apk

My AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.amedya.amedyaeu">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="eu.amedya.amedyaeu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <service
        android:name=".MesajServisi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".IDServisi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</manifest>
```

Firebase Cloud Messaging and Android WebView project.
Error:(14) Error: The  element must be a direct child of the  element [WrongManifestParent]

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

Thank you for your reply.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.amedya.amedyaeu">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="eu.amedya.amedyaeu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<service
        android:name=".MesajServisi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".IDServisi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout official doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.amedya.amedyaeu">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="eu.amedya.amedyaeu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<service
        android:name=".MesajServisi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".IDServisi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your mentifest file with these :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="eu.amedya.amedyaeu">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name="eu.amedya.amedyaeu.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

  <service
            android:name=".MesajServisi" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".IDServisi" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        </application>


    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <service
        android:name=".MesajServisi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".IDServisi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Put this lines inside your application tag

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Put these tag insid your `application` tag as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.amedya.amedyaeu">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="eu.amedya.amedyaeu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MesajServisi" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".IDServisi" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```